# Comment form throwing "this field required" on submit

Tags: comment-form

I'm not sure how long this has been happening, but I realized today that the comment form on a site of mine is throwing this error:

> The form you submitted contained the following errors
>
> The name field is required
>   The email field is required

This is happening even when both fields are filled out.

My template code is here: http://pastie.org/6168028

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you post the complete code for the entire template to www.pastie.org and post the link back here?

Comment: Here's the code: http://pastie.org/6168028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding names to your form fields that correspond to the EE comment fields? I believe these would be required for the form to work.

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="comment_name" placeholder="Enter your name.">
<input name="email" type="email" id="comment_email" placeholder="Enter your email."> ...etc
```

Comment: Indeed, the `name` property is definitely required.